# Square root recursive

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a recursive method that will display a sequence of squared numbers from one to a specified maximum number, n. The format of the presentation will be to display first, the sequence of odd numbers squared, starting from the largest odd number (<= n) to the smallest odd number (1), then displaying the even numbers squared, starting with the smallest even number (2) to the largest even number (<= n). I am getting an error message that uninitialized local variable 'upperB' is being used. Any ideas?

```
 #include "stdafx.h" 
 #include <iostream> 
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <math.h>\
using namespace std; 
int main()
//Input a,b are constants,lower and upper approximation points as well as 
//precision value N   
{ double a, b, N, lowerB, upperB;
cout << "Give me a value for a: ";
cin >> a;
cout << "Give me a value for b: ";
cin >> b;
cout << "Give me a precision :";
cin >> N;
cout << " Give me  lower and upper approximations: ";
cin >> lowerB, upperB;
cout << "The root is : " <<
RootFinderSMNEW(a, b,  lowerB, upperB, N) << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
    }

double f( double x, double a, double b)
{
    return sin((a* x) / (1 + x*x))*atan(b*x) + atan(x);
}

double RootFinderSMNEW(double a, double b, double lowerB, double upperB, int N)
{
    double f_left = f(lowerB, a, b);
    double now = lowerB + N;
    double f_right = f(now, a, b);
    while (f_left * f_right > 0 && now < lowerB)
    {
        f_left = f_right;
        now += N;
        f_right = f(now, a, b);
    }
    return now - N / 2;
}
```

Comment: With a little effort you could have reduced the code to half a dozen lines that still reproduced the error. This ability to prepare a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a vital skill, much more valuable than any one bug fix.

Comment: If the answer fixed your problem, you're supposed to click the checkmark to mark the question as completed. that lets other people know it's done.

Answer (score 4):

You mean

```
cin >> lowerB >> upperB;
```

not

```
cin >> lowerB, upperB;
```

What you're doing is not putting a value into upperB, so it's not initialized. Which is exactly what the error message says.